# No lines of output shown after importing pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I installed pandas through pip, but when I import it, the code runs but no output is shown at all, right after the import statement. 
Here's a sample of my code

```
import xlrd, xlwt
print("1")
import pandas as pd
print("2")
from math import trunc
```

1 is printed, but 2 isn't. After 1 is printed, the script just hangs for a few seconds and terminates. This occurs regardless of the code written below the import statement. I also seem to get the same error for the openpyxl module. Does anyone know a fix to this?

Comment: Where is your dataframe? would be great few could share few lines of code or errors.

Comment: does the script terminate with any error message?

Comment: I tried your code snippet and it works fine for me. 1 and 2 are printed. Try uninstalling and installing Pandas.